# Understanding Thread.Sleep use in WCF

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I am doing streaming using nVLC and WCF like a remote control and i have the following doubt. In the StartTransmission() operation, if i call player.Play() and not call Thread.Sleep(0) the method end and nothing happened. But with Thread.Sleep(0) the method end but streaming is functioning now. the answers are.

1. Has Thread.Sleep a particular functionality inside WCF remote procedure?
2. How the Main Thread lifetime work when i use Thread.Sleep(0).

Comment: Post some code perhaps

Answer (score 2):

1. No, none.
2. There is no main thread in WCF. Maybe the nVLC library has one.

This looks like a race condition. The small time it takes for `Thread.Sleep(0)` to complete seems to be enough to the nVLC complete it's work.

I was thinking about COM message pumping as well, but `Thread.Sleep(0)` [does not do that.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/274eh01d(v=vs.110).aspx)